# Is there a way to find only unused JSDoc type definitions?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc

For example:

```
/**
 * A number, or a string containing a number.
 * @typedef {(number|string)} NumberLike
 *
 * Dummy type
 * @typedef {(string|null)} StringLike
 */

/**
 * Set the magic number.
 * @param {NumberLike} x - The magic number.
 */
function setMagicNumber(x) {
}
```

As you can see `NumberLike` is used, but the `StringLike` type is not used and I'd like to find all such unused type definitions on our project. It's a Nodejs project with [typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript) installed.

Here's our `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "noEmit": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
  },
}
```

Comment: When you say "find", what do you mean _specifically/literally_ (in detail)?

Comment: @jsejcksn, just seeing the list of unused types would be sufficient for me (so I can remove them)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not presently familiar with AST tools (which I think would be the domain of tools for finding this information). However, here's an example to illustrate an idea:

Let's say that the example JavaScript file in your post is saved at `./module.mjs`. Here's another module, `./find-typedefs.mjs`:

```js
import {promises as fs} from 'fs';

function getTypedefNames (sourceText) {
  const regex = /@typedef\s+{[^}]+}\s+[A-Za-z]+/g;
  return [...new Set((sourceText.match(regex) ?? [])
    .map(str => str.split(/\s+/).slice(-1)[0]))];
}

async function main () {
  const [filePath] = process.argv.slice(2)
  const text = await fs.readFile(filePath, {encoding: 'utf8'});
  const names = getTypedefNames(text);
  console.log(names.join('\n'));
}

main();
```

Running the file outputs this:

```
$ node find-typedefs.mjs module.mjs
NumberLike
StringLike
```

By using the function `getTypedefNames` as a basis for potentially more abstractions, you could automate searching the files in your project to produce a list of names that you can then search (and, for example, count) in each file. If you are using an editor like VS Code, you can also use regular expressions (like the one in that function) directly in the editor's Find menu.

Hopefully this will save you some manual work of eye-scanning.